# IE Browser issue

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am creating a LI and appending it to the UL using JQUERY code.

```
     listHtml = "<li id='ordli' whereaboutid='' action='Insert' onthefly='True' class='myDragClass'>" +
    "<div class='orderBox'>" +
    "<span><a href='#' id='114' title='delete' class='itemOrderDelete'>X</a></span></div>" +
    "</li>";

$(this).append(listHtml);
```

The issue is, IE renders the **href** with the page url instead of #.

```
In Firefox 

<a href='#' id='114' title='delete' class='itemOrderDelete'>X</a>

This is correct

But in IE (Compatibility mode)

<a href='http://localhost:1224/pages/index.aspx#' id='114' title='delete' class='itemOrderDelete'>X</a>

This is incorrect
```

Any idea why the URL is appended in HREF. How to eliminate it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this breaking something for you?  I believe '#' and '(url)#' should mean the same thing to the browser.

Comment: Don't use numbers as you element's ID attribute

Comment: for some reason i need to keep it as '#' and i have some js login.

Comment: Don't use numbers as you element's ID attribute – Joey 1 min ago     - Is that the cause for the issue

Comment: Do you need the `#` in order to prevent link from triggering?

In that case you can use `href="javascript:void(0)"` instead.

Comment: @ZenMaster that behavior is discouraged. Either use `href="./"` (won't prevent link following) or `id="foo" href="#foo"` (will keep the link in-page).

Comment: You probably aren't going to be able to eliminate the url. If that's what old IE wants, that what old IE is going to get.  This isn't a jQuery issue, but a baked in IE issue.

Comment: You cannot start your `id` with a number.

Comment: @Matt McDonald really? Care to provide a link, I would like to see the reasoning...

EDIT (my bad, wrong link)... still - I would like to see the article

Comment: @ZenMaster : href="javascript:void(0)" prevents the URL in href.. Thanks cheers.

Comment: One question.. i am using 114 as ID but i don't have problem.. is it a serious issue?

Comment: Why would you expect to have a problem?

Comment: Is ID the cause for the URL issue? if so i will change the id and keep '#'

Comment: I don't think it has any relation. What Sparky672 meant to say (incorrectly) is that in general ID attribute of an HTML element follows a set of rules - one of which is to not start with a digit.
On practice, however, digits work just as well, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, that happens to IE9 in IE7 compatibility, you can try this fix:

**FOR TEST**

HTML:

JS

```
var listHtml = $('<li id="ordli" whereaboutid="" action="Insert" onthefly="True" class="myDragClass"> \
    <div class="orderBox"> \
    <span><a href="" id="114" title="delete" class="itemOrderDelete">X</a></span></div> \
    </li>');

$(listHtml).find('a').attr('href', '#');

$('ul').append(listHtml);

alert($('ul').html());
```

[test](http://jsfiddle.net/N3C7c/1/)

Comment: Thank you .. Instead ZenMaster gave a trick and it worked. check the comments.